# How to use the proxy used in Internet Explorer in an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, proxy

In my ASP.NET application I am using the WebRequest class and I want to use the default system proxy. Here is the code I am using.

```
private static bool CheckIfUriIsReachable(string uri)
{
    bool reachable = true;

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "HEAD";

    var proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();

    proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.Proxy = proxy;

    HttpWebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        reachable = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }

    return reachable ;
}
```

This works perfectly well when run as part of a console application - it correctly picks up the system proxy (I assume the IE proxy for the signed-on user on the PC), However, this does not work when run as part of an ASP.NET application on the same machine. No proxy is found.

I assume this is because ASP.NET is running under a user account that does not have an IE proxy setting in the system registry. I have tried to include the following in the web.config file but this does not work.

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy>
       <proxy usesystemdefault="true" />
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

My question is how to setup an ASP.NET 3.5 application to correctly use the default proxy used by IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not system-wide default proxy. Thus you can only use th configuration of the current user. If there is no such configuration, you have a problem.

You can try to run the app pool of your ASP.NET application under a user with a proxy configuration or look into group policies, which, AFAIK, do support setting a system-wide proxy.

Comment: This is exactly right. We use Windows Authentication and we would face setting up each user account on that machine with the proxy settings. The better solution is one account at the app pool level.