# Proxy on Http Bindings

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, proxy, web-config

I have a web application connects web service on a machine uses proxy server. Connections are ok on internet explorer as shown in image

[image: Proxy settings]
And my web.config is:

```
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy>
            <proxy autoDetect="true" usesystemdefault="true"/>
        </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
   <system.serviceModel>


       <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>

            <binding name="ProcessSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"

useDefaultWebProxy="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
               messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                >
               <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                  maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
               <security mode="None">

               </security>
            </binding>
         </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
         <endpoint address="http://www.serveraddressthatiwanttoconnect.com/services/WebService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProcessSoap"
        contract="PINAlmaServis.ProcessSoap" name="ProcessSoap" />
  </client>
```

I want to use system proxy settings, because it can change time to time. "kurumsalproxy" is a machine name on local network. I tried every potential variations for web.config on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx but can not establish to connect.

Is there something that i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use system proxy settings

There is no “system” proxy settings. Every user owns personal proxy configuration. You could create a user with the proxy configuration and change app pool identity to use that account.

UPDATE: [How to use the proxy used in Internet Explorer in an ASP.NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756217/how-to-use-the-proxy-used-in-internet-explorer-in-an-asp-net-application)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change application pool identity, if you carefully read this server fault thread,

https://serverfault.com/questions/34940/how-do-i-configure-proxy-settings-for-local-system

You need to configure the proxy setting for system accounts (local system, local service, and network service) if your application pool identity is Network Service.